# Strange behavior on AVR port when configuring one pin as input and other as output

Tags: c, avr

In a basic project I'm using one pin of portD on ATmega32 as input hocked up with a switch and another pin as output hocked with a led when i'm configuring the input pin (pin 0) as in and configure the pull up resistor then configure the output pin (1) as output then burn the code 
I got very low brightness from LED although i tried to configure the DDRD on one line the code worked well any suggestions of this problem

the faulty code

```
void main(){
DDRD&=~(0x01);
PORTD|=0x01;
DDRD|=0x02;

while(1)
{

    if((PIND & (1<<0)) == 0 )
    {
        PORTD|=0x02;
    }
    else
    {
        PORTD&=~(0x02);
    }

}
return;
}
```

The code that works as expected (works well),

```
void main(){
DDRD=0b00000010;
PORTD|=0x01;
while(1)
{

    if((PIND & (1<<0)) == 0 )
    {
        PORTD|=0x02;
    }
    else
    {
        PORTD&=~(0x02);
    }

 }
return;
}
```

any one know the reason of this behavior

Comment: do you have any schematics? How is the LED connected? What the LED? What the supply voltage?

Answer (score 0):

You switch the internal pin  pull up on.  Read the the DS for more details